# No EFI system partition was found during reinstallation of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I'm trying to **reinstall Ubuntu** 20.04 i.e. keep personal files, but reinstall system files, and without breaking the windows boot which is on the same drive.

When I go through the steps I get stuck on.

[image]

My question is I **already see an efi boot partition** on the drive, which is labelled windows boot manager.

So when I try to make another partition with the efi mount point I get an error saying you cannot have two file systems on the same mount point.

[image: pic2]

Any ideas?

Comment: Turn off bit locker.  Make sure Windows fast start up is off, also.

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying to install Ubuntu as UEFI too? Also, why are you doing the something else option?

Comment: @sasuke you're right. I changed the screenshot. I actually was using the normal option.

Comment: @oldfred I need to keep bitlocker though

Comment: Then you probably need to install to a different drive where Windows is not seen. Either a second internal drive if system can do that or an external drive. I found an external SSD drive in USB3 port to be almost as fast as an internal drive. My USB3 flash drives were very slow loading and particularly slow writing, so thought at least some was due to USB3 port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into the exact same problem today. Select your /dev/nvme0n1p1 (the Windows Boot Manager), hit the "Change..." button, and change the type to EFI System Partition. It'll want to write that change to disk, so let it. Then hit the dropdown for "Device for boot loader installation" and change it to that partition, /dev/nvme0n1p1. Hit install, and the only warning I got at that point was that it was going to reformat the swap partition, which is perfectly fine.